# Почему не происходит перезаписи значений параметров ф-ции?

Tags: javascript, функции, параметры

Не понимаю почему не происходит перезапись значения аргумента ф-ции на `undefined`? Я всегда думал, что параметры - это своего рода переменные, только локальные:

```js
//пример с функцией
function func(a, b = 10) {
  console.log(a, b);
};
func('word', undefined); //'word' 10 --> перезаписи на undefined не происходит 

//пример с переменной
let a = 5;
a = undefined;
console.log(a); //undefined --> перезапись происходит
```

Почему так работает? Значение по умолчанию у аргумента имеет приоритет?

Comment: undefined - Переменная, не имеющая присвоенного значения (из документации). Делай вывод

Comment: `function func(a, b = 10) { console.log(a, b); b = undefined; console.log(a, b); } func('word', undefined);`

Answer (score 0):

Значение по умолчанию - это подстановка значения вместо undefined в момент вызова, а не фоллбэк для переменной.

```js
function func(a, b = 10) {
  console.log(a, b);
  b = undefined;
  console.log(a, b);
  ++b;
  console.log(a, b);
}

func('word', undefined);
```

Работает примерно так:

```js
function func(a, b) {
  if (b === undefined) b = 10;

  console.log(a, b);
  b = undefined;
  console.log(a, b);
  ++b;
  console.log(a, b);
}

func('word', undefined);
```

А вовсе не так:

```js
function func(a, b) {
  with ({
    __proto__: null,
    get b() { return b === undefined ? 10 : b },
    set b(x) { b = x },
  }) {
    console.log(a, b);
    b = undefined;
    console.log(a, b);
    ++b;
    console.log(a, b);
  }
}

func('word', undefined);
```

Comment: А разве стандартный аргумент не применяется когда введённый аргумент является falsy? (Или nullish, не помню точно)

Comment: @ΝNL993, нет, только undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Это происходит из-за того, что если вы вовсе не передадите параметр он по умолчанию будет как undefined.

Пример:

```js
function foo(a){
   console.log(a)
}
foo()
/// вывод в логах undefined
```

Вы предположили, что если в переменную передать undefined то оно перезапишется, но это не так и сработало это только из-за метода console.log.

Пример где не перезаписывается если передать переменную:

```js
const foo = (a,b=40)=>{
  console.log(a,b)
}
let c = undefined
foo('word',c)
```

Тут возникает вопрос, а возможно ли определять передал ли программист осознанно undefined или же его сам подставил механизм языка.
И да это возможно реализовать с помощью arguments или же Spread syntax.

```js
function foo(a,...args){
  let b
  if(args.length===0){
    b=20 //// допустим что 20 это число по умолчанию
  }else{
    b=args[0]
  }
  console.log(a,b)
}
foo('123')
foo('123',undefined)
foo('123',1,2,3)
```

Comment: _"Пример где не перезаписывается если передать переменную"_ - что не перезаписывается?